# Visual Studio 2008 List of all functions in file

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2008 you can view all functions in a dropdown menu.
I need to copy this list, is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013 you can copy them from Class View, give that a try in 2018 it might work for you.